# Is there any XML like programming lanuage?

Tags: xml, programming-languages

Is there any XML like programming lanuage?

For example this code in C:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
  int result;
  result = a+b;
  return result;
}
```

Write like this:

```
<function name="add">

  <parameters>
    <parameter name="a" type="int" />
    <parameter name="b" type="int" />
  </parameters>

  <body>

    <variables>
      <variable name="result" type="int" />
    </variables>

    <statements>

      <statement>
        result = a+b
      </statement>

    </statements>

  </body>

  <return>result</return>

</function>
```

Comment: Hopefully your next question will ask about code generation for this theoretical language, as surely you don't want to type all of that?

Comment: Sounds like a nice way to convert 6 lines of code into 17 (ignoring blank lines!). You are though describing some elements of XSLT (ish - sort of - not really!)

Comment: You need a lot more lines here - you've not declared the return type, for formalized the actual statement section.

Comment: You know, a few years ago someone at Microsoft released an April fools joke that basically suggested they were turning C# into an XML based format...

Comment: @Yuck: Type more characters does not mean the language is weak. for example in BASIC `print sin(3.14)` is shorter than a C program, but it does not mean `C is weaker than BASIC`.

Comment: @Amir Saniyan: My comment isn't against the expressiveness of an XML language, but how it affects developer productivity. More characters means more time spent typing and an increased opportunity for typos.

Comment: And it's not just the time spent writing. Too much terseness makes code cryptic, yes, but after a certain threshold, more characters just waste the reader's time without any addition of clarity. And your example has long passed this threshold.

Answer (score 6):

Yes there are. [Jelly](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/) is an XML based java language. I often cite it during talks, I use it as an example of a terrible idea. It is a disaster.

Comment: I just noticed the warning at the top of the project phase. Apparently they are experiencing a period of low developer involvement. Probably because people have realized what a dumb idea it is.

Answer (score 4):

XSLT [is Turing Complete](http://www.unidex.com/turing/utm.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned Lisp since it's literally programming in an abstract syntax tree (AST). It's not XML but it's substantially less verbose.

```
(defun add (a, b)
  (+ a b))
```